# Where date is 01/09/?

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my where clause at the minute i just have

```
WHERE StartDate <= '09/01/2019 00:0:0'
AND EndDate >= '09/01/2019 00:0:0'
```

This date is the last occurance of 01 September. Which is 2019, but come 01/09 this year it will be 2020

My question is can I automate this where clause so i dont have to go in and change it manually each year?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Something similar to `YEAR(NOW())`? Not really sure what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the most recent September with the following logic:

```
where startdate <= datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -9, getdate())), 9, 1) and
      enddate >= datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -9, getdate())), 9, 1)
```

This subtracts 9 months from the current date and uses the year for that.  So on Aug 31, the year is the previous year.  On Sep 1 it "magically" (well, artimetically) switches to the current year.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date  NVARCHAR(30)

set @Date = CONCAT('01/09/', DATEPART(YEAR,getdate()))

.. WHERE StartDate<= @Date
```